# After saving data, Why does ms-access say write conflict

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have written a front end application with MS Access.

I have an edit module that controls the forms controls for any changes. It does this by creating a recordset of the current data, and if the data changes then the edit functions will save the data to the table. The data itself is never bound to the form, it gets it's data via defined strings.

There are also a few subforms!

The problem is when I change the current record it asks me whether to save the data, displaying the built-in Write Conflict error:

[image: Conflict axample]

Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can resolve this?

Comment: After reading [This post][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578452/suppress-write-conflict-message-in-access-vba

I found out that all I had to do is pass my form over to the my IfModified function, and just add "frm.Dirty = false."

It just goes to show, that it is mostly always something simple lol :-) sorry that I cant answer the post as I am not able :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [suppress write conflict message in Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578452/suppress-write-conflict-message-in-access-vba)